# I found that my iota tokens are stolen

Tags: transaction, wallet, balances

After logging into my trinity_wallet after a long time (several monthes), I found a zero balance and lastest transaction which was not mine. After correspondence with a team member, it became clear that the tokens were stolen. Will IOTA Fundation return tokens ?

Comment: In case the fraudulent transaction was in February (or earlier), you have good chances that the IF will reimburse you. Best to contact them directly on Discord. They may ask you to report the theft to your local police. In case the fraudulent transaction was later, I don't know what their policy is.

Comment: it was in march

Comment: Thats messed up I think that I was hacked as well

Answer (score 1):

The IOTA Foundation does not have the power to refund a transaction once it has been issued.